# Why after the third row the float property does not work correctly?

Tags: html, css, css-float

After some rows the css float property have a strange behavior that i couldn't know its reason.[image: see image]

---

Take into account that I cannot add a div with a "clear" property between the rows because the html will be generated dynamically (php loop).

I think that in order to do that I should create a function in php that determines when to insert a clear div between the rows because sometimes there are 2 images per and other times 3.

But I prefer a CSS solution.

Here is the full code:

```css
.row {
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.boxes{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;   
}

.box1 {
    width: 33.33333333333333%;
}

.box2 {
    width: 66.66666666666666%;
}

.box-inner {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box1 boxes">
        <div class="box-inner">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/390/244?random=1" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box1 boxes">
        <div class="box-inner">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/390/244?random=1" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box1 boxes">
        <div class="box-inner">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/390/244?random=1" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box1 boxes">
        <div class="box-inner">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/390/244?random=1" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box2 boxes">
        <div class="box-inner">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/770/238?random=1" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box2 boxes">
        <div class="box-inner">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/770/238?random=1" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box1 boxes">
        <div class="box-inner">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/390/244?random=1" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box1 boxes">
        <div class="box-inner">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/390/244?random=1" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box1 boxes">
        <div class="box-inner">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/390/244?random=1" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box1 boxes">
        <div class="box-inner">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/390/244?random=1" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: use inline-block or flexbox instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you have an image that's slightly shorter than the one before it. That's causing the gap on the following row which `clear` would normally fix. if you had the same number of elements per row then something like `nth-child` could be used with clear, but since you said the number of elements per line could change, that wouldn't work. An easy fix is to set a minimum height on your `.box-inner` class:

```css
.row {
  width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.boxes {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.box1 {
  width: 33.33333333333333%;
}

.box2 {
  width: 66.66666666666666%;
}

.box-inner {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 122px;
}

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box1 boxes">
    <div class="box-inner">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/390/244?random=1" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box1 boxes">
    <div class="box-inner">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/390/244?random=1" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box1 boxes">
    <div class="box-inner">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/390/244?random=1" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box1 boxes">
    <div class="box-inner">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/390/244?random=1" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box2 boxes">
    <div class="box-inner">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/770/238?random=1" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box2 boxes">
    <div class="box-inner">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/770/238?random=1" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box1 boxes">
    <div class="box-inner">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/390/244?random=1" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box1 boxes">
    <div class="box-inner">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/390/244?random=1" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box1 boxes">
    <div class="box-inner">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/390/244?random=1" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box1 boxes">
    <div class="box-inner">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/390/244?random=1" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to add a fixed height to your container.

```
.box-inner {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Another addition to the above is to add object-fit: cover to your image to ensure it fills the container space.

```
.box-inner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}
```